# Set a custom "forwarded" message to Mail Item via VSTO Outlook 2013 Plugin

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am developing a VSTO Plugin for Outlook 2013 (or higher) that allows users to forward mail contents and sender/recipient data to some other program. The sending of mail data works great, I would however like to mark the mail in Outlook that I forwarded, so that the user can clearly see which mails were forwarded.

I have tried several options, which worked for me, but the end result is not quite what I would like.

For example:

- I can set a category for the mail with a custom text "Mail forwarded
  to XY"
- I can set one of the Outlook Icons as the symbol (`PidTagIconIndex`)

One option I didn't try yet is creating a `custom Form` and I would like to avoid that option if possible.

What I would like to do is set something like this (sorry for the german screenshot):

[image]

This text appears when I forward a mail to some other recipient in Outlook. Is it possible to set this programatically (with C#) - if possible with custom text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED` (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003`) and `PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME` (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10820040`) using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty` - take a look at an existing message with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author - click IMessage button).

Comment: Tnx for your reply, I assume however that setting a custom text will not be possible without creating a custom form?

Comment: Yes, either a custom category or your own task pane.